# Alpine shell can't find file in docker

Tags: linux, docker, alpine

I've set up a simple docker container with Alpine and a tool called bowtie2. When I try to run `bowtie2-align-s`, I get this error:

```
sh: ./bowtie2-align-s: not found
```

However, `ls` tells me that the file is there. I installed bowtie2 from a Linux binary distribution. How would I tell if that distribution is compatible with Alpine Linux? I'm running docker 17.09.0-ce on Ubuntu 16.04.

Here's the full Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:3.6

ENV BOWTIE2_VERSION 2.2.8

RUN apk add --no-cache \
        perl \
        wget \
        openssl \
        ca-certificates \
        strace \
    && wget https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/bowtie-bio/bowtie2/$BOWTIE2_VERSION/bowtie2-$BOWTIE2_VERSION-linux-x86_64.zip \
    && unzip -d /usr/local bowtie2-$BOWTIE2_VERSION-linux-x86_64.zip \
    && rm bowtie2-$BOWTIE2_VERSION-linux-x86_64.zip
```

I test it like this:

```
$ sudo docker run -it --rm --security-opt seccomp:unconfined bowtie2-bin sh
/ # /usr/local/bowtie2-2.2.8/bowtie2-align-s --version
sh: /usr/local/bowtie2-2.2.8/bowtie2-align-s: not found
/ # ls -l /usr/local/bowtie2-2.2.8/bowtie2-align-s
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root      11600541 Nov 15 18:49 /usr/local/bowtie2-2.2.8/bowtie2-align-s
/ # strace -v -s 1000 /usr/local/bowtie2-2.2.8/bowtie2-align-s --version
execve("/usr/local/bowtie2-2.2.8/bowtie2-align-s", ["/usr/local/bowtie2-2.2.8/bowtie2-align-s", "--version"], ["HOSTNAME=a72609479c9a", "SHLVL=1", "HOME=/root", "TERM=xterm", "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin", "BOWTIE2_VERSION=2.2.8", "PWD=/"]) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
writev(2, [{iov_base="strace: exec: No such file or directory", iov_len=39}, {iov_base="\n", iov_len=1}], 2strace: exec: No such file or directory
) = 40
writev(2, [{iov_base="", iov_len=0}, {iov_base=NULL, iov_len=0}], 2) = 0
getpid()                                = 11
exit_group(1)                           = ?
+++ exited with 1 +++
/ #
```

I run docker with unconfined access to allow `strace` to run. You can see that `ls` finds the file, but `sh` doesn't seem to. `strace` doesn't seem to show any other files being accessed, so what is going on?

Comment: What does `file /usr/local/bowtie2-2.2.8/bowtie2-align-s` output?

Comment: Thanks, @BMitch, that showed me that it needed `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`. I posted the results as an answer.

Answer (score 11):

Thanks to [BMitch's comment](https://serverfault.com/q/883625/1143#comment1139245_883625), I found the answer. I needed the `libc6-compat` package for GNU libc compatibility. Here's the fixed version of the docker file:

```
FROM alpine:3.6

ENV BOWTIE2_VERSION 2.2.8

RUN apk add --no-cache \
        perl \
        wget \
        openssl \
        ca-certificates \
        libc6-compat \
        libstdc++ \
    && wget https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/bowtie-bio/bowtie2/$BOWTIE2_VERSION/bowtie2-$BOWTIE2_VERSION-linux-x86_64.zip \
    && unzip -d /usr/local bowtie2-$BOWTIE2_VERSION-linux-x86_64.zip \
    && rm bowtie2-$BOWTIE2_VERSION-linux-x86_64.zip
```

I also got it working when I built bowtie2 from source, so I think I'll go with that. I'm not sure how reliable the compatibility package is.

If you want all the details, I had to install the `file` package to follow BMitch's suggestion:

```
$ sudo docker run --rm -it bowtie2-bin sh
/ # apk update
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.6/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.6/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
v3.6.2-201-g6289c8472a [http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.6/main]
v3.6.2-203-g6070fe8ac2 [http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.6/community]
OK: 8438 distinct packages available
/ # apk add file
(1/2) Installing libmagic (5.32-r0)
(2/2) Installing file (5.32-r0)
Executing busybox-1.26.2-r7.trigger
OK: 50 MiB in 21 packages
/ # file /usr/local/bowtie2-2.2.8/bowtie2-align-s
/usr/local/bowtie2-2.2.8/bowtie2-align-s: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.9, with debug_info, not stripped
```

The interpreter `interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` looked suspicious to me, and Alpine Linux doesn't have a `/lib64` folder. A little searching found a [related discussion](https://github.com/gliderlabs/docker-alpine/issues/219#issuecomment-254741346):

> The binary you try to run is linked against GNU libc so it will not work, just like binaries compiled for windows or OSX will not work.
>
> That said, musl libc provides partial GNU libc compatibility, which means that some binaries will actually work, even if there are no guarantee. Try `apk add libc6-compat`. It may or may not work.

I tried that, and found that I also needed the `libstdc++` package. Now it works well enough to report the version number.